# OpenBMC with Raspberry Pi (2 or 3) and build bmcweb?

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, openbmc

Has anyone built the `meta-raspberrypi` target for https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc with some patch to build the `bmcweb` application into the resulting image? I've spent some time trying to learn enough about Yocto to do this myself, but it's a steep learning curve. I see evidence that Intel, IBM, and others have builds for their platforms with `bmcweb`. I think I just need a little help connecting the dots here.

Comment: Did you try to add [meta-phosphor](https://github.com/openbmc/meta-phosphor) with `meta-raspberrypi`?

Comment: Actually yes. That's one of the dots I need to connect. I did, but a bunch of other required packages reared up and said "no build success". I have now asked on the OpenBMC github issues page and it appears I'm seeing something known and not yet fix merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code commits have stalled out a bit but the code behind this tag has been shown to work with getting OpenBMC to work on Rasberry Pi

https://gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz/q/topic:%22raspberrypi%22+(status:open%20OR%20status:merged)

Multiple people have pulled it down and built an OpenBMC image that works on Rasberry.

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work after a bit of effort to build stacks of layers. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @AlanMimms, since you succeeded in that task, could you share some tips and advices how to do that? Maybe you have some step-by-step tutorial, that would be great! If not, is it enough to use above link to get it running out of the box. Could you also share your use case of OpenBMC on the Raspberry Pi platform?

Comment: I'll try to do that soon when I get some time.